# Awk to get same column with maximum filed

Tags: linux, awk, grep, paste

I have two files. I have to get matching name from file1, print the entire content of file1, and add a fourth column (exp) in file 1 using a second file with max value

```
file1

name             value1          value2          value3
hat_197050       30.5348         37.2617         1.2203
hat_160460       20.8679         21.0134         1.00697
hat_092950       63.875          63.2321         0.989935

file2

hat_160460  AA:0003700,AA:0003707,AA:0005634,AA:0006355,AA:0043401 
hat_160460  AA:0003700,AA:0003707
```

Desired output:

```
name             value1          value2          value3  exp
hat_197050       30.5348         37.2617         1.2203
hat_160460       20.8679         21.0134         1.00697 AA:0003700,AA:0003707,AA:0005634,AA:0006355,AA:0043401 
hat_092950       63.875          63.2321         0.989935
```

I want to use `awk`.
I write this two get matched column but it gives just matched

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$1]){print }}' file1 file2 > matched
this command to get the file2 with max field
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ;{if (NF > max) {max = NF ; line =$0}} END{print line}' file2
```

I don't figure out how I combine both to get what I want. Any suggested reading will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        # Read file1
        i=$1;
        sub($1 FS, "");
        a[i]=$0; next;
    }
    (FNR < NR) && (FNR == 1) {
        # add new column header to title row (first line of file1)
        print $0 "exp"; next;
    }
    { 
        # Read file2 and append matching line from file1
        print $0 a[$1];
    }
' file2 file1
```

Note that `file2` is read before `file1` in the solution above to extract the first column to match (and therefore `file2` is specified before `file1`). Also, this solution will use the **last match** in `file2` (in your example, `hat_160460` occurs twice in `file2`).

Result:

```
file1 name value1 value2 value3 exp
hat_197050 30.5348 37.2617 1.2203 
hat_160460 20.8679 21.0134 1.00697 AA:0003700,AA:0003707
hat_092950 63.875 63.2321 0.989935
```

If you want to use the **first match** in `file2`, then replace the `FNR == NR` section above with

```
FNR == NR {
    # Read file1
    i=$1;
    sub($1 FS, "");
    if (! a[i]) a[i]=$0;
    next;
}
```

Result:

```
file1 name value1 value2 value3 exp
hat_197050 30.5348 37.2617 1.2203 
hat_160460 20.8679 21.0134 1.00697 AA:0003700,AA:0003707,AA:0005634,AA:0006355,AA:0043401 
hat_092950 63.875 63.2321 0.989935
```

Comment: one more thing can we use && many times in awk command like this                                                                                                                 awk '{if($4 >= 0.9 && $4 <= 1.1 && $7 >= 0.9 && $7 <= 1.1) print $0}'

Comment: @star Yes, that is ok.